# Navigation Drawer android

Tags: java, android

У меня имеется класс `UserConfig`, в котором я храню данные о пользователе. Возможно ли из данного класса заполнять данными `Navigation Drawer` при том, что при каждом вызове Navigation эти данные отображались?

Answer (score 0):

Да, можно. У Navigation Drawer есть колбэк `onDrawerOpened()` - именно в нём можно обновить содержимое левого меню. Если смо меню сделано через `NavigationView`, то заполнять его данными надо в методе `onPrepareOptionMenu()` а вызывать перерисовку методом `supoortInvalidateOptionsMenu()`

Comment: я создал в классе userConfig метод :  public setInformation (Activity activity){   ((TextView)activity.findviewById(R.id.my_header_nav)).setTex("Text"); } Но данный метод не записывает в меню данные. Как быть?

Comment: @ДмитрийКоверко, попробуйте через NavigationView искать. Т.е. как-то так: `TextView tv = (TextView)((NavigationView)activity.findviewById(R.id.NAVIGATION_VIEW_ID)).getHeaderView(0).findViewById(R.id.my_header_nav);`

Comment: подчеркивает R.layout.nav_header_main. (nav_header_main идет как layout).

Comment: @ДмитрийКоверко, я вас не понял, но, может, вам надо id а не layout написать?

Comment: а как я layout через R.id. укажу. (Я создал новый проект с шаблоном NawigationDrawer и хочу в хидер записать свой текст и подставить фото, но реализовать это в другом класее). И nav_header_main находится в папке layout. Вот. Вроде бы разъяснил))

Comment: @ДмитрийКоверко, метод findViewById требует  ID в качестве аргумента. И искать вам надо не разметку хэдера, а NAvigationView, в нём получить хэдер методом getHeader(0), а уже в нём искать текстовое поле. Ещё раз постотрите код выше\

Comment: подчеркивает все выражение после знака =.

Comment: @ДмитрийКоверко, ну, попробуйте разбить выражение на части - принцип верный и работать будет